# oredr by desc not working on order by clause after using extract inside order by

Tags: mysql

trying to use order by after performing extract in bdate

```
 Select bdate 
    from employee
    Order by extract(year from bdate), extract(month from bdate), extract(day from bdate)
```

The output comes

```
bdate
1937-01-09
1941-01-09
1955-01-09
1962-01-09
```

and when i am using desc in order by

```
    Select bdate 
    from employee
    Order by extract(year from bdate), extract(month from bdate), extract(day from bdate) desc

;
```

again the output is same as above

Comment: `ORDER BY bdate DESC`

Comment: All rows are unique by first expression (`extract(year from bdate)`). So the rest expressions did nothing (with or without DESC).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select bdate 
 from employee
 Order by extract(year from bdate), extract(month from bdate), extract(day from bdate) DESC
```

is equal to:

```
 Select bdate 
 from employee
 Order by extract(year from bdate) ASC, extract(month from bdate) ASC, extract(day from bdate) DESC
```

SO both queries will result in the list being ordered by the year of bdate in ascending order. Then the month in ascending order, then the day in decsending order. If you want to order all columns descending you would need to place the DESC keyword on all columns in the ORDER BY:

```
 Select bdate 
 from employee
 Order by extract(year from bdate) DESC, extract(month from bdate) DESC, extract(day from bdate) DESC
```

Or in this case as already mentioned by @Cid you could just order by the whole bdate without extracting, this should give the same result:

```
Select bdate 
from employee
Order by bdate DESC
```